# SBT plugin just for your local machine

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, sbt-plugin

Often time, I need to add SBT plugin which is not applicable to the project but just for myself. For example, I use eclipse as my IDE so I want to enable this plugin for all my SBT projects without having to include it in plugin.sbt file. This is because my colleagues might be using different editors so it doesn't make sense to check in this plugin to the source control. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can add plugins(and settings) globally by placing them in `~/.sbt/`.

The path for global plugins is `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt` (until 0.12.X) and `~/.sbt/<version>/plugins/build.sbt` (starting with 0.13.x).

Reference:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Global-Settings.html#Global+Settings+using+a+Global+Plugin

Comment: What Jhonny says works fine. For example, I like using Sublime Text and Ensime for editing Scala code. I don't want to "force" the plugins to each project's setting though, just because I happen to have that preference.  So I have the plugins sbt-sublime [https://github.com/orrsella/sbt-sublime] and ensime-sbt [https://github.com/ensime/ensime-sbt] enabled in my personal ~/.sbt/0.13.X/plugins.sbt file